# !!python/object:__main__.ClassName throwing exception

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file: `./YAML/simpleData.yml`

```
- name: 'Somu'
  age:  26
  content:
  - name: 'Neo'
    age:  27
    content: []
  - name: 'Ari'
    age:  26
    content: []
```

And I'm trying to parse it using PyYAML via:

```
import yaml
# Creating objects directly with the YAML module:
print("Attempting Direct Object Load: ")


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, con):
        self.name = name
        self.age = hp
        self.content = con

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=%r, hp=%r, sp=%r)" % (
            self.__class__.__name__, self.name, self.age, self.content)

    def printData(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.age)
        if self.content:
            for per in self.content:
                print("-->", end="")
                per.printData()


# Data load:
person_obj = None
data = ""
try:
    with open('YAML/simpleData.yml') as source:
        for line in source:
            data += line
except Exception as err:
    print("An exception occurred: " + str(err))

person_obj = yaml.load("""!!python/object:__main__.Person\n""" + data)

if not person_obj:
    print("Data Loading Failed..! EXITING!!")
    exit(1)

person_obj.printData()
```

I'm new to Python, and thus can't determine what I'm doing wrong, due to which this exception is being raised:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: expected a mapping node, but found sequence
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 1:
    !!python/object:__main__.Person
    ^
```

How do I fix this?

---

### Full Output Dump:

```
Attempting Direct Object Load: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somu/Programming/python/HeadFirstPython/yamlIntro.py", line 106, in <module>
    person_obj = yaml.load("""!!python/object:__main__.Person\n""" + data)
  File "/home/somu/Programming/python/HeadFirstPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 72, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/home/somu/Programming/python/HeadFirstPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    return self.construct_document(node)
  File "/home/somu/Programming/python/HeadFirstPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 46, in construct_document
    for dummy in generator:
  File "/home/somu/Programming/python/HeadFirstPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 578, in construct_python_object
    state = self.construct_mapping(node, deep=deep)
  File "/home/somu/Programming/python/HeadFirstPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 204, in construct_mapping
    return super().construct_mapping(node, deep=deep)
  File "/home/somu/Programming/python/HeadFirstPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 122, in construct_mapping
    node.start_mark)
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: expected a mapping node, but found sequence
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 1:
    !!python/object:__main__.Person
    ^

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error message says it all: a mapping (dictionary) is needed, but your YAML file contains a sequence (list).

Comment: @tinita But doesnt the YAML module know how to handle YAML arrays?

Comment: Of course PyYAML knows how to handle arrays (sequences). But a Person object needs to be serialized as a mapping.

Answer (score 1):

At the root, c.q. top level, of your file you have a sequence. The first element of which is a mapping with among others the key-value pair `name`: `Somu`.

If you want to load this using PyYAML in the way you described, you should strip of the first two characters of each line:

```
data += line[2:]
```

or insert the `!!python/object:__main__.Person` after the first dash:

```
data = data.replace('- ', '- !!python/object:__main__.Person\n', 1)
```